# Default mobile browser zoom only in Safari and IE mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, safari, zooming

Does anyone know why despite using the meta viewport tag, if a min-width is assigned to the body, Safari and IE mobile still zoom pages in on load? I've searched a lot, but my specific case doesn't seem to be documented, so I'll go into full details.

I already have this in the header:

```
<meta name="Viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and my pages are scaled perfectly in Android browsers. In each stylesheet is this code to enforce the proportions in case a stylesheet is incorrectly loaded:

```
body {
    min-width:(whatever the minimum device width is for the media query);
}
```

so for the iPhone 4 and other high DPI displays, I have:

```
body {
    min-width:640px;
}
```

When I remove the min-width, the scale appears massively zoomed in on iPhone 4, but with no sidescrolling, i.e. the text is massive, but the width isn't actually overflowing anymore. Compared to Androids loading the same stylesheet and appearing perfectly, this is completely wrong. I can fix it by changing the  tag to read:

```
<meta name="Viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">
```

but this simply causes tiny text zoom problems in all other browsers. Causing a problem for most to cater for few. No good.

It is important to note here that some mobile browsers read different media queries based on their default zoom settings. Here's what goes on in my case (simplified media queries to save space):

```
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width:0px) and (max-device-width:1280px)" href="webfiles/mob_default.css" />
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width:640px) and (max-device-width:1280px)" href="webfiles/mob_vhigh.css" />
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width:480px) and (max-device-width:639px)" href="webfiles/mob_high.css" />
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width:360px) and (max-device-width:479px)" href="webfiles/mob_mid.css" />
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width:0px) and (max-device-width:359px)" href="webfiles/mob_small.css" />
<link media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (min-device-width:640px)" href="webfiles/mob_vhigh.css" />
```

On a Motorola RAZR (540x800px) using the default Android browser, when the default zoom is set to:

- 'far', it will load the 480-639px wide stylesheet. (correct for the physical resolution of the screen)
- 'mid', it loads the 360-479px wide stylesheet
- 'close' loads the '0-359px wide stylesheet

While this is actually a more elegant way of handling zoom rather than physically zooming in on the page and requiring sidescrolling, not knowing how the default zoom was handled caused a lot of wasted time trying to find out why my media queries 'weren't working'.

The reason I mentioned all that is there are apparently no options to adjust the default zoom settings on IE mobile or Safari (I have also tested this in Dolphin on iPhone, same results). I wanted to check in case Safari, Dolphin and IE mob handled zoom differently. Since my problem was originally plaguing Android and working fine in Safari and Dolphin (before I added the <meta="Viewport"...> tag), the default zoom was my only suspect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iPhone 4 and other high res displays set the min-width to 320px to account for the 2:1 pixel ratio.

Comment: I tried that earlier, it removes the overflow, but all content is still blown up far too large. It is worth noting that while the page loads zoomed in in portrait mode, when I load it in landscape, it loads perfectly, then when I flip to portrait mode, it resizes perfectly.

Comment: Do you have a sample we could look at?

Comment: I'm afraid not, but basically the page loads zoomed-in at approx 200% (in portrait mode). In landscape, it loads perfectly, then if I change the orientation to portrait without refreshing the page, it resizes nicely. I cannot work out what is causing this insane zoom. The body{ min-width:640px;} shouldn't cause anything like this, since that's the horizontal width of the iPhone 4...

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. It now works nicely on iPhone 4-5, but any jQuery requesting the width of the screen still pulls 320px instead of 640px. It's a little weird. Also, Windows Phones behave a little similar but load zoomed in to 320px regardless of physical resolution if you include 'targetdevicedpi=devicedpi'(?) in the meta viewport tag.